# Clone or Reuse Element in Lightning Flow Builder or Visual Workflow

Tags: visual-workflow, visual-flows

Say if I have an Assignment element that takes in a number variable and then increments it. I'd like to reuse that same element multiple times in different places. Can I do that? At least in Lightning Flow Builder it looks like I have to create it manually each time.

Edit: perhaps I could use Sub-flows - create one for each reusable function, and reference that. It could take in params, work on them, then return them...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To actually reuse a single element that performs a specific function, using a subflow is best.

In reusing an element in a single flow, it would get complicated to know where you were coming from and where to go next, I don't really see how it would work.

Now If you are asking about an option to clone a button, I'm told that will be coming in the next release or two.  It was available in the old flow designer but is not yet in LFB.